# Is there a way to add a suffix to files where the suffix comes from a list in a text file?

Tags: bash

So currently the searches are coming up with a single word renaming solution, where you define the (static) suffix within the code. I need to rename based on a text based filelist and so -

I have a list of files in /home/linux/test/ :

```
1000.ext
1001.ext
1002.ext
1003.ext
1004.ext
```

Then I have a txt file (labels.txt) containing the labels I want to use:

```
Alpha
Beta
Charlie
Delta
Echo
```

I want to rename the files to look like (example1):

```
1000 - Alpha.ext
1001 - Beta.ext
1002 - Charlie.ext
1003 - Delta.ext
1004 - Echo.ext
```

How would you a script which renames all the files in /home/linux/test/ to the list in example1?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

Use `paste` to loop through the two lists in parallel. Split the filenames into the prefix and extension, then combine everything to make the new filenames.

```
dir=/home/linux/test
for file in "$dir"/*.ext
do
    read -r label
    prefix=${file%.*} # remove everything from last .
    ext=${file##*.}   # remove everything before last .
    mv "$file" "$prefix - $label.$ext"
done < labels.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it works very well, One thing with this… I think it doesn’t account for missing files, for example if I have
1001.ext
1002.ext
1003.ext
1005.ext
1006.ext
1010.ext

It renames 1005.ext with the name supposed to be for 1004.ext, then it renames 1006.ext with the name supposed to be for 1005.ext, then it renames 1010.ext with the name supposed to be for 1006.ext

Comment: How is the code supposed to know which labels are supposed to go with which filenames?

Answer (score 0):

I originally partly got the request wrong, although this step is still useful, because it gives you the filenames you need.

```
#!/bin/sh

count=1000
cp labels.txt stack

cat > ed1 <<EOF
1p
q
EOF

cat > ed2 <<EOF
1d
wq
EOF

next () {
[ -s stack ] && main
}

main () {
line="$(ed -s stack < ed1)"
echo "${count} - ${line}.ext" >> newfile
ed -s stack < ed2
count=$(($count+1))
next
}

next
```

Now we just need to move the files:-

```
cp newfile stack
for i in *.ext
do
newname="$(ed -s stack < ed1)"
mv -v "${i}" "${newname}"
ed -s stack < ed2
done

rm -v ./ed1
rm -v ./ed2
rm -v ./stack
rm -v ./newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

On the possibility that you don't have exactly the same number of files as labels, I set it up to cycle a couple of arrays in pseudo-parallel.

```
$: cat script
#!/bin/env bash
lst=( *.ext )                  # array of files to rename
mapfile -t labels < labels.txt # array of labels to attach
for ndx in ${!lst[@]}          # for each filename's numeric index 
do # assign the new name
   new="${lst[ndx]/.ext/ - ${labels[ndx%${#labels[@]}]}.ext}"
   # show the command to rename the file
   echo "mv \"${lst[ndx]}\" \"$new\"" 
done

$: ls -1 *ext # I added an extra file
1000.ext
1001.ext
1002.ext
1003.ext
1004.ext
1005.ext

$: ./script # loops back if more files than labels
mv "1000.ext" "1000 - Alpha.ext"
mv "1001.ext" "1001 - Beta.ext"
mv "1002.ext" "1002 - Charlie.ext"
mv "1003.ext" "1003 - Delta.ext"
mv "1004.ext" "1004 - Echo.ext"
mv "1005.ext" "1005 - Alpha.ext"

$: ./script > do # use ./script to write ./do
$: ./do          # use ./do to change the names
$: ls -1
'1000 - Alpha.ext'
'1001 - Beta.ext'
'1002 - Charlie.ext'
'1003 - Delta.ext'
'1004 - Echo.ext'
'1005 - Alpha.ext'
do
labels.txt
script
```

You can just remove the `echo` to have `./script` rename the files there.
I renamed `labels` to `labels.txt` to match your example.

If you aren't using `bash` this will need a call to something like `sed` or `awk`. Here's a short `awk`-based script that will do the same.

```
$: cat script2
#!/bin/env sh
printf "%s\n" *.ext > files.txt
awk 'NR==FNR{label[i++]=$0}
     NR>FNR{ if (! label[i] ) { i=0 } cmd="mv \""$0"\" \""gensub(/[.]ext/, " - "label[i++]".ext", 1)"\"";
      print cmd;
      # system(cmd);
}' labels.txt files.txt
```

Uncomment the `system` line to make it actually do the renames as well.
It *does* assume your filenames don't have embedded newlines. Let us know if that's a problem.

Comment: This one seems the easiest to understand, but I seem to be going wrong somewhere:
/Users/linux/test/script: line 3: labels: No such file or directory
/Users/linux/test/script: line 6: ndx%0: division by 0 (error token is "0")

I guess the first done is the end of the script, or does it end with:

do
labels
script

Apologies for failing, I'm a bit of a dumdum

Comment: `< labels` should be `< labels.txt`

Comment: c.f. the `ls -1` output at the bottom of my post. My file was `labels` with no extension, though the OP did add a `.txt`. I agree it would have been more consistent for me to use the same name, though.

Comment: Is it possible you aren't using `bash`? That will matter for this.

Comment: Added an `awk` based answer too.